# Not sure how to decode msds-revealedusers attribute which is set on a read only domain controller

Tags: powershell

trying to see if anyone succeeded in pulling this from powershell... There is a constructed attribute for a read only domain controller , which contains details about the cached accounts in it, msds-revealedusers .see command below ...................................................... Get-ADComputer Readonlydomaincontrollername -Server NAMEOFDOMAIN -Properties msds-revealedusers | select -ExpandProperty msds-revealedusers.
its a binary data, but trying to convert it into readable value as you see in the GUI in ADUC for the Read only domain controller ...
B:96:A00009001B0000004DCAD20F03000000F6781F56E3FEDD48818E932B355D4113CF836322000000009F4FAC1C00000000:CN=USERNAMEOU=OU1,OU=DC,OU=WHATEVER,OU=WHENEVER,DC=DC,DC=DOMAIN,DC=com
above is the data you get out with powershell , but the actual values via gui should be something with the lmpwdhistory,ntpwdhistory etc

Comment: usually the decode comes like below

Comment: dn:CN=BLAH,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=BLAH1,DC=BLAH,DC=com 
 >msDS-RevealedUsers: lmPwdHistory                     3  2017/08/30-15:00:58   563818751  {561F78F6-FEE3-48DD-818E-932B355D4113}  CN=BLAH USER - b0h001,OU=BLAH,OU=BLDC=BLAH1,DC=BLAH,DC=com

Comment: after more reading found that this value is as described here  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd240133.aspx

Comment: "An octet string that contains a binary value and a distinguished name (DN)" ......i have no idea what that means, but hoping there is a way in powershell to decode this

Comment: I don't have a read only DC to test on, found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.adaptercodemethods.convertdnwithbinarytostring?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0. Maybe able to [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] and see if you can convert? Maybe helps. Thanks, Tim.

Comment: I also found this page but it isn't rendering properly and I can't click on the PowerShell example: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ms180871(v=vs.80)

Comment: Can you try -properties msds-revealedlist. From this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223662.aspx which then refers to this one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc220361.aspx it says is a more usable form of this attribute is the constructed attribute msDS-RevealedList